# GWT: how to format number on server and client (Gin/Guice)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, number-formatting, decimalformat

In my GWT + App Engine project, I have a function that formats a `double` into a `String` that I need to use on the client and server side.

As you cannot use `DecimalFormat` in GWT, you have to use `NumberFormat` on the client-side, and `DecimalFormat` on the server-side.

I have a class that is used on both sides of the wire (`UnitRate`) which needs to use this function, so I implemented two classes: `ClientUtilities` and `ServerUtilities` which both implement the `Utilities` interface like so:

```
public interface Utilities extends Serializable
{   
    public String formatUnitOnePlace(Double value);
}

public class ClientUtilities implements Utilities
{
    @Override
    public String formatUnitOnePlace(Double value)
    {
        NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getFormat("#0.0");
        return fmt.format(value);
    }
}

public class ServerUtilities implements Utilities
{
    @Override
    public String formatUnitOnePlace(Double value)
    {
        DecimalFormat oneDigit = new DecimalFormat("#0.0");// format to 1 decimal place
        return oneDigit.format(value);
    }
}
```

The initial idea was to bind the classes using Gin/Guice and inject `Utilities` into the `UnitRate` class so that the right implementation gets used depending which side of the wire we are on. `UnitRate` can be a child of `Offer` (server-side) and `OfferDto` (client-side), but this is seeming like a rather long-winded way to do it as the `UnitRate` entities need to be created by hand, and the only way to do it I have managed is using Assisted Injection.

This however which is creating a ripple effect through the program meaning that more and more of my domain model has dependencies so need to be created by Gin/Guice which is obviously not ideal.

See usage here:

```
public class UnitRate implements Serializable, HasUnitType, Comparable<HasUnitType>,     HasTotal
{
    // omitted for brevity  
    private Utilities utilities;

    @AssistedInject
    private UnitRate(@Assisted UnitType unitType, Utilities utilities)
    {
        this.unitType = unitType;
        this.price = "";
        this.utilities = utilities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTotal()
    {
        // some calculations first...
        return utilities.formatUnitOnePlace(result);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what the ideal solution for this would be...

I could go the route of not using DecimalFormat and NumberFormat altogether and implementing some kind of math-based solution, but I'd rather not.

I could split `UnitRate` into `UnitRate` and `UnitRateDto` but I don't see the point - they are never stored in the datastore and only ever exist as child entities of another.

How do I solve this problem? **WHY, GWT, WHY?**

(I'd just like to add that this is highly simplified. In reality there are other formatting things the Utilities interface needs to do, and other places it needs to be used/injected.)

Comment: Did you try approach from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13828293/2564898 ?

Answer (score -1):

You may be able to get this working by using the @GwtIncompatible for the method where you are trying to retrieve the DecimalFormat class. This notifies the compiler to ignore this method and or class. Take a look at com.google.gwt.core.shared.GwtIncompatible for more info on how the annotation works.

Let me know if this solves your issue.

This might solve your issue btw.

```
@GwtIncompatible
public class ServerUtilities implements Utilities
{
    @Override
    public String formatUnitOnePlace(Double value)
    {
        DecimalFormat oneDigit = new DecimalFormat("#0.0");// format to 1 decimal place
        return oneDigit.format(value);
    }
}
```